# Redirect all URLs starting with a substring to a new url in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla3.0, redirect

I had to re-design a Joomla Listing site and the website used a component to show the listings. The url of the each item is as follows

example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/xxxxx

The xxxx is usually a combination of id and alias, so it might be something like this

example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/1-programmer

Anyways, what i'm trying to do is, to redirect all urls that are example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/xxxxx to
example.com/gulf-job-listing

I tried to use the Joomla core redirect but i was only able to redirect only one url to another. i.e. i redirected example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/   to   example.com/gulf-job-listing

my .htaccess file is as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On



RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood right, put this line just after RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/ /gulf-job-listing [L,R]
```

Comment: I would like to add anything that has a url structure of example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/xxxxxxxx to example.com/gulf-job-listing. The xxxxx can be anything. I am able to redirect it without the xxxxx, the problem is i want to redirect everything and anything that has the above structure.

Comment: Do you want to save this xxxx for example,  /gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/xxxx to /gulf-job-listing/xxxx ?

Comment: No, Since it's an entirely new module im using, i just want to redirect every single listing to the list category page. So,      example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/1-programmer      or        example.com/gulf-job-listing/jobs/items/view/1547-Officer should all be redirected to        example.com/gulf-job-listing/  which is the current category page.

Comment: The rule in answer do the same. don't it?

Comment: I tried that, when i place the code in the middle of the .htaccess file, just before the first 
RewriteRule .* index.php [F], it shows me an error 403 forbidden page. When i place the code at the bottom just below RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]   , i still get the 404 page

Comment: Put it just after RewriteEngine On

Comment: That's awesome, it worked! I put it right after the first RewriteEngine On, and it worked! You should include that in your answer. Is there any resource you recommend that will give me a good idea and examples of .htaccess files just like the above?

Comment: Sorry, i can't because i read only docs plus have some expirience